# How do I send this multipart/form-data to a Web Service using Genexus?

Tags: genexus

The Following CUrl works perfectly whenever I test it:

```
curl --request PUT \
 --url https://api.sandbox.URL_HERE/document-analysis/90471702021 \
 --header 'Accept: application/json' \
 --header 'Authorization: Bearer AUTH_TOKEN' \
 --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001' \
 --header 'api-version: 1.0' \
 --form documentType=RG \
 --form documentSide=FRONT \
 --form 'image=data:image/jpeg;name=RG_Front.jpg;base64,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'
```

The Base64 string above was cut just to fit the comment field, but you get the idea.

I just have to send some info to the endpoint using HTTPClient but got stuck especially because Genexus says that the line is too big when I try to convert the image (1Mb) to a base64 string.
Has anyone gone through that?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Web Service is expecting the new "multipart/form-data" instead of the old "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" for uploading files as explained [here](https://everything.curl.dev/http/postvspost) and the specification section for forms in HTML 4.01 is [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4). So, going to your question, I think that you can use the AddFile method of the HTTPClient data type (as explained [here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?7046,AddFile%20method)) to get your client working. Readink the wiki, it says:

> In particular, if the content of the HttpClient message is multipart / form-data (given by Content-Type Header), then the AddFile method adds the file as multipart. In this case, the second parameter is needed to indicate the name of the variable that the file represents. Also, you have to necessarily precede your sentence with a header that specifies a specific Content-Type, like this:
> &Httpclient.Addheader("Content-Type", !"multipart/form-data")

I say "I think" because I dindn't test myself, you can try and let us know if it works or not.